# Scraping a dynamically generated webpage with HTML5 <input> field

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, web-scraping

I want to collect data from [this page](https://medium.com/collections). I have keywords I want to input in the search box, which is defined as an HTML5 `<input>` with an `eventlistener` that dynamically changes the page based on the query.

For example, I want a script that inputs the term "hello world" in the search field and then scrapes the dynamically generated content, say the name of the collections that appear. Because of the Same Origin Policy I can't use JavaScript and I've spent the last 3 hours looking into Python but couldn't find anything there.

I can't tell if this is so obvious no one writes/asks about it, or it's a clever way to not let scripts scrape from your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the page in **Chrome's Debugger** or **Firebug in Firefox** and look at the **Network Tab** and find out the AJAX requests the JavaScript is doing when you enter text into the input field(s).

Then write a webscraper using any of:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spyda
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scrapy

Comment: Thank you James this is exactly what I needed! Thanks for the Chrome trick. I tried what you suggested but when I submit a request: 
r = requests.get('https://medium.com/search/collections?q=hello')
print r.status_code
I get a 400 status code instead of 200 -- any thoughts?

Comment: Whatever request you submit -- you will have to comply their their ToS, rules and other restrictions they may have put in place. i.e: Don't abuse their Web API(s), etc...

Comment: Ah so Medium could reject my request since it's no coming from their webpage?

Comment: See: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html -- It means you've submitted a bad request. It should be: ``request.get(url, data)`` where ``data`` is a dictionary of key/value pairs.

Comment: James, thanks for the clarification. I assume I am only passing the 'q' parameter but instead I must pass the entire request header that appears in the Chrome debugger:
accept:application/json
accept-encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
content-type:application/json
host:medium.com
method:GET
referer:https://medium.com/collections
scheme:https
url:/search/collections?q=hello
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
version:HTTP/1.1
x-xsrf-token:1

Comment: Most likely. Be careful to not abuse their service however, it may be rate limited or they may get very upset if you write code that hammers their service.

Comment: Thank you James. I got a 200 response after I passed the entire request (e.g. r = requests.get('https://medium.com/search/collections', params={'q':'startup'}, headers={'method': 'GET', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch', 'url': '/search/collections?q=hello', ...)